# Execution plan of aggregate query in MongoTempate with Spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using spring data mongodb, in that want aggregation query to implement that I am using MongoTemplate with aggregation method. When I trace the log it shows the query as follows:

```
find: track.$cmd { "aggregate" : "stayRecord" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "vehicleId" : { "$all" : [ 10]}}} , { "$match" : { "stayTime" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2016-06-20T18:30:00.000Z"}}}} , { "$match" : { "stayTime" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-06-21T18:30:00.000Z"}}}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$stayTime" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}}}
```

I want to know execution plan for this query.
How can I find out if my indexes are used during that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that in order to follow the below steps, you need the working aggregate query which mongo shell can understand.

**Follow the below steps:-**

1) Go to mongo shell 
2) Execute the use command to switch to your database

```
use <database name>
```

3) Execute the below query. I hope the aggregate query mentioned in the thread is syntactically correct. Also, please **change the collection name accordingly** in the below syntax.

db.**yourCollectionName**.explain().aggregate({ "stayRecord" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "vehicleId" : { "$all" : [ 10]}}} , { "$match" : { "stayTime" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2016-06-20T18:30:00.000Z"}}}} , { "$match" : { "stayTime" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-06-21T18:30:00.000Z"}}}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$stayTime" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}}});

2) In the output, please find the "winningPlan" element. In the input stage ("inputStage") attribute, if the query used index it will show you the value as **"IXSCAN"** and the index name if the query used index. Otherwise, it would show **"COLLSCAN"** which means the query used the collection scan (i.e. index is not used).

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SKIP",
                "skipAmount" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "user.followers_count" : {
                            "$gt" : 1000
                        }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "created_at" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "created_at_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "direction" : "backward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "created_at" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer. Easily saved me an hour.